# How to find the origin of a Magento layout file

Tags: php, magento

I'm pretty new to Magento and the whole layout system is pretty confusing but i'm trying to learn it. There is one thing i still can't figure out is how to know the origin of the layout file, like where was it included.

Take poll layout file as an example, so i can see the layout file in folder `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/poll.xml`

And i do see the `<reference>` tag that is including the poll into the `right` block, but how can Magento know that it will need to read `poll.xml`? Or it will normally read all of the xml files and include stuffs when needed? What if i want to remove the poll in my theme, what can i do rather than modifying the core layout?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Magento!  Despite someone down voting you, that's a good question with a few complicated answers.

In Magento 1, every module (files in `app/code/core`, `app/code/community`, and `app/code/local`) have a `config.xml` file.  This files configures many things.  One of those things is a layout handle XML file.  If this node is present, Magento will know it needs to load that particular layout file.

In the case of your specific `poll.xml` file, you can find it configured here

```
<!-- File: app/code/core/Mage/Poll/etc/config.xml -->
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <poll>
                <file>poll.xml</file>
            </poll>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Comment: After 2 days messing around with Magento i'm getting more used to it now and understanding better how the files are loaded, thanks for the answer, it helped a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help @LongMKNguyễn -- I don't know if it would be right for you or not, but I'm the developer of a software product called Commerce Bug (https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3) -- it can help you find the files you need when you're doing Magento (1 or 2) development!

Comment: It did help, i read some of your blog when learning about magento layout actually, thanks for the contribution to the community!